# Android Studio Main Menu Bar Not Showing on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, navigation

I have a Mac Book pro with macOs Catalina version 10.15. I recently installed android studio but I cant find the main menu bar which contains items such as - **File, Edit, View, Code, Navigate, Build, Run, VCS, Window, Help** etc

[Main Menu Bar On Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK7r2.png)

I have tried so many things like -

1. Shift (Twice) - Opens Settings - Type Main Menu (Under Actions) - Tick Include Disabled Options - The toggle for Main Menu seems to be "ON" and I cant switch it off or toggle
2. CMD + , - Keymap - Main Menu - View -Appearance Main Menu - Add Keyboard Shortcut - J - Apply - OK - I clicked J but nothing shows
3. Shift (Twice) - Opens Settings - Types Main Menu - Click on it - Click on View - Appearance - I only found "Toolbar", "Status Bar", "Navigation Bar"...etc I cant find Main Menu so I can mark/check it like others.
4. Downloaded Java For Mac Os 2017 - I tried to install but it said I already have the latest version installed

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it back, you simply need to move your pointer to the top screen edge and it will magically reappear. Move you mouse pointer away and the menu bar will again disappear.